# Swift, add button with constrains to view programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uitableview

I have a view in tableviewCell and I want to add button and add constrains for this button with the view

like facebook question

Comment: Your question is not clear, also mark the view in the screenshot you want to play wid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your question is not very clear, i would have to drop only this:

```
YOURVIEW.addSubview(YOURBUTTON)
```

**iOS 9+**

```
YOURVIEW.addSubview(YOURBUTTON)

YOURBUTTON.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
YOURBUTTON.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(YOURVIEW.topAnchor).active = true
YOURBUTTON.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(YOURVIEW.bottomAnchor).active = true
YOURBUTTON.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(YOURVIEW.leadingAnchor).active = true       
YOURBUTTON.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(YOURVIEW.trailingAnchor).active = true
```

**iOS 6+**

```
let view = ["yourButotn": YOURBUTTON]
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[yourButotn]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[yourButotn]-|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
```

this will add the constraints

Comment: this dont available in ios8 or 7 it's only for ios9

Comment: well the question doesn't stipulate the iOS version